# Extracts incomplete cases from a data set in r

Tags: r

from this example:

```
    ## x
   ##  v1 v2 v3
   ##1 90 55 NA
   ##2 NA 45  8
   ##3 85 NA  5
   ##4 NA 33  7
   ##5 55 30  4
   ##6 60 20  3
   ##7 75 15  2
   ##8 80 23  6
     # ici is where Incomplete case indicator 

     ici=(function (x) 
     return(is.na(x)))

    ici(x)
            v1    v2    v3
  ##  [1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  ##  [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  ##  [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  ##  [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  ##  [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ##  [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ##  [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ##  [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE

     # Extracts incomplete cases from a data set

     ic=(function (x, drop) 
     return(x[ici(x)]))(x, drop)

     ic(x)
   ## Error: could not find function "ic"
```

from the last run ( Error: could not find function "ic") why it give me this and how I solve this broblem with function ic

Comment: but is give me this `FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE `     but i want to extract all instances that contain NA

Comment: But I want to solve my function problem I mean (ic)

Comment: [Use correct R notation for creating a function](http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html). Now the question is: What do you want `drop` to do? Why don't you want to use `complete.cases`?

Comment: I will do it , but I want to help me to  fix ic function that will give me the same result like `x[!complete.cases(x), ]`  .

Answer (score 4):

I don't quite understand what your function `ic` is doing, including brackets and the `drop` bit.

If you want complete cases, the most handy way is `na.omit(x)` or `x[complete.cases(x), ]`. But since you want incomplete cases, we need `x[!complete.cases(x), ]`.

I certainly understand what `ici` is doing. It is just `is.na`. If I were asked to start from `is.na`, I would use the following:

```
x[rowSums(is.na(x)) > 0L, ]
```